# Pinvoke the procedure entry point RegGetValueW

Tags: c#

Im calling loadlibrary (tried EX too) in c# which calls the procedure entry point [RegGetValueW](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms724868%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) under the covers which does not exist on XP/32bit.

what can you do?

Comment: Is there any "W" function that actually _does_ exist under 32-bit Windows? You could try installing and using [MSLU](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Microsoft_Layer_for_Unicode).

Comment: Please show some relevant code. I find it hard to believe that [`LoadLibrary()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms684175(v=vs.85).aspx), with _"Minimum supported client: Windows XP"_, itself calls [`RegGetValue[W]()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms724868(v=vs.85).aspx), with _"Minimum supported client: Windows Vista, Windows XP Professional x64 Edition"_.

Comment: [DllImport("kernel32.dll")]
    static extern IntPtr LoadLibrary(string dllName);

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        try
        {
            IntPtr userApi = LoadLibrary("my.dll");
            if (userApi == IntPtr.Zero)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Unable to load library error: {0}", Marshal.GetLastWin32Error());
            }
        }

Comment: @capsch Update the question instead of writing a comment. And please be as precise as you can.

Comment: Just don't.  Use the .NET RegistryKey.GetValue() method instead.